# Orcacle Apex Trigger

Tags: oracle, triggers, oracle-apex

I have a notes form which i am calling on two different pages and storing data in the same table on page one the parameter is p4_clid and on page 2 it is p21_entity. when i enter data on page one the data gets inserted but on page two it does not, how do i pass my page two parameter in trigger.

```
create or replace TRIGGER  "BI_f_41" 
  before insert or update on "f_41"
  for each row
    begin
        if inserting and :new.FORMRESPONSEID is null then
            select "NEW_F41_SEQ".nextval
            into :new.FORMRESPONSEID
            from dual;
        end if;
        if inserting then
            :new.SubjectID           := get_subidn(v('P4_CLID')) ;
            :new.FORMID              := 41 ;
            :new.subjecttypeid       := 1 ;
            :new.responseCreatedDate := localtimestamp;
            :new.ProgramID           := get_pgmid(v('P4_CLID')) ;
            :new.AuditStaffID        := v('SESSION_GIHUID');
            :new.AuditDate           := localtimestamp;
        end if;
        if updating then
            :new.AuditDate := localtimestamp;
        end if;
    end;
```

Comment: First of all your approach is not correct. Use page process to do the DML operation. Here in your code when you have given v('P4_CHILD') then how can you expect the value of P21_ENTITY item.

Comment: I am using page process DML only for Insert update and delete. like i said i have a form which i am calling on two different pages, one page identified as p4_clid and the other by p21_entity, when i  do DMl on p4_clid page it works and now  i need to do dml on p21. How do i pass both the item values in my trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your specific question, you could I suppose do this in your trigger:

Wherever you have:

```
v('P4_CLID')
```

Replace by:

```
case [something that indicates the calling page]*
  when 4 then v('P4_CLID')
  when 21 then v('P21_ENTITY')
  end
```

(* I was going to say `nv('APP_PAGE_ID')` but that will always return the ID of your form page, so that won't work.)

I have to agree with the comment that said your approach is not correct.

The normal approach is to have a hidden item in your form page - let's say your form page is page 33 and the item is `P33_ID`.  When you call the form from page 4 you pass in the value of P4_CLID in the URL:

```
f?p=...:P33_ID,...:&P4_CLID,...
```

From page 21 you pass in the value of P21_ENTITY instead:

```
f?p=...:P33_ID,...:&P21_ENTITY,...
```

You then use the value of P33_ID in your INSERT statement directly - not in a database trigger.

It is generally bad practice to have dependencies on APEX session state within database code including triggers, because it assumes that the one and only way the data can ever be inserted/updated/deleted is via your APEX application. That may be true for you now, but it is not future-proof.